# MySQL before update trigger an insert syntax error using PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

```
 CREATE TRIGGER question_preserver BEFORE UPDATE ON bank
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 IF TRIM(NEW.question) != TRIM(OLD.question) THEN
 INSERT INTO bank_question_history (id,old_question) VALUES (OLD.id,OLD.question)$$
 END IF$$
 END$$
```

I am inserting that query into Mysql using PHPMyAdmin's SQL window, using a delim of $$.  I get an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5`

I'm sure it's something obvious and I'm just missing it, but no matter what I try I can't get it to work.  The error is not helpful at all, and from what I have researched I am doing this exactly like 4-5 examples I found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go figure I figured it out right after asking.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER question_preserver BEFORE UPDATE ON bank
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 IF TRIM(NEW.question) != TRIM(OLD.question) THEN
 INSERT INTO bank_question_history (id,old_question) VALUES (OLD.`id`,OLD.`question`);
 END IF;
 END$$
```

You have to use `;` to break each statement/command and your delim `$$` to end the entire trigger.

Comment: Well done for figuring out the answer yourself. Yes, the delimiter is for the trigger statement, whilst the normal delimiter should be used for SQL within the trigger